# add children and grandchildren to array using mysql_query WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress, children

I'm trying to accomplish the following to run queries on a WordPress database:

1. use a mysql PDO prepare function to retrieve child posts of selected parents
2. use another PDO prepare function to retrieve grandchild posts
3. incorporate all of these into a single array (same key)

I've gotten as far as displaying the children, but having trouble adding grandchildren into the array. Here's the code:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['selected'];
$a = implode(',', array_map('intval', $id));

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'victoria_wp_site';
$password = 'PASSWORD';

$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=victoria_wp_site;host=$hostname", $username, $password);

$qry = $db->prepare("SELECT id,post_title 
          FROM `wp_posts` 
         WHERE `post_parent` IN ($a) and post_name not like '%revision%' ");
$qry->execute();

$i = 0;
while ($data = $qry->fetch()) {
    $result[$i] = $data;
    $i++;
}
        
$b = implode(',', array_column($result, 'id'));

$qry_grandchild = $db->prepare("SELECT id, post_title 
          FROM `wp_posts` 
         WHERE `post_parent` IN ($b) AND post_name not like '%revision%' ");
$qry_grandchild->execute();      

     
while ($data = $qry_grandchild->fetch()) {
    $result[$i] = $data;
    $i++;
}       

echo json_encode($result);
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - the original code was not my own, so I'm trying to work with what's already there without having to re-write everything. The part I'm trying to add is to include the grandchildren. Are you recommending i re-write the whole thing?

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance on this (this is a new area for me), but could you provide any more detail, or perhaps a reliable resource that's relevant to accomplishing that?
P.s. - you mentioned the logic is fine, but I'm still only getting the children (not grandchildren). Something is missing or wrong but i can't pinpoint it

Comment: Please be aware that the `mysql_xx` functions are obsolete and *have been removed* from the most recent versions of PHP. If your code uses these functions, it is already incompatible with the current mainline PHP version.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent - indeed my apologies. I should have specified this is for accessing posts in a WordPress database. As mentioned I am new to MySQL queries and am working with existing code

Comment: Got it, thanks Ryan. I'm a long time lurker new poster here,but will try to get better I promise! I've updated the question

Comment: I've updated the code to PDO, but seem to still be hitting the same issues. Any further help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This is not how you use prepared statements.  This script should be using placeholders and bound parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the format of the array used to select the grandchildren. I solved this by adding the implode function to the array before using it to select grandchildren.

```
$b = implode(',', array_column($result, 'id'));

$qry_grandchild = $db->prepare("SELECT id, post_title 
          FROM `wp_posts` 
         WHERE `post_parent` IN ($b) AND post_name not like '%revision%' ");
$qry_grandchild->execute();
```